# How to use the basename of the collected log file or its directory name as a field in filebeat?

Tags: filebeat

I want to collect logs in `/var/log/*/*.log` using `filebeat`.
To indentify the log lines, I want to use the filename and the dirname as a field, like

```
processors:
  - add_fields:
      target: ""
      fields:
        dirname: "$(dirname log.path.file)"
        filename: "$(basename log.path.file)"
```

Do we have a method to achieve this? Thanks in advance!